# SVG to PNG - Always broken

Tags: c#, svg

I have tried so many things but it seems like whatever I do, I cannot successfully convert SVG to PNG

My scenario is the following

1. Load SVG file from URL into `ContentStream`
2. Convert it using to PNG using '[SVG](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Svg/)' Nuget package
3. Save the PNG to `MemoryStream`
4. Upload it to Azure from `MemoryStream`

My code looks like the following (It's pretty straightforward for the most part)

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://myweburl/foo.svg");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        HttpContent content = response.Content;
        var contentStream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var SVG_FILE = SvgDocument.Open<SvgDocument>(contentStream);
        SVG_FILE.ShapeRendering = SvgShapeRendering.Auto;
        var bitmap = SVG_FILE.Draw(200, 200);
        using (var MS = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(MS, ImageFormat.Png);
            CloudBlockBlob blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("foo.png");
            MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(MS);
            return blob.Name;
        }                        
    }
    else
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the STREAM for SVG is fine but when I convert it to PNG it ends up being all boxes etc

**SVG**

[image]

**PNG**

[image]

I tried different settings in `var bitmap = SVG_FILE.Draw(200, 200);` such as increasing the height and width and update `SvgShapeRendering` settings but same results.

Any idea why I am unable to use `bitmap.Save` to properly render PNG?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you write the PNG output to a file rather than upload it to Azure?  Also, can you share a test SVG image that shows this problem?  (The "SVG" image in your question is actually a PNG.)  Also, are you using .NET Core or .NET Framework?  I ask all this because I put together a quick test project that uses the Svg library to convert an SVG to a PNG and it worked as I expected it to.

Comment: Hi @LukeWoodward I am using .NET framework, the actual SVG can be found here  "https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/avataaars/hello.svg" {pick any please} It could be that these SVG's are bit complicated and SVG Lib is failing to convert it or unless i am doing horribly wrong

Comment: I get similar behaviour to you with that SVG.  Your code looks correct, it looks more like the SVG library is failing to convert these images for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for testing it out @LukeWoodward - I am not sure what else I Can do, Probably find a different SVG avatar API but really appreciate testing on your end